# Trying to simplify Powershell Code to Single Line

Tags: powershell

The following snippet of code gets a list of paths, converts each character of each path to its ASCII value and stores this in a variable named $output

```
 $itemlist = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path "$data_path").FullName 
 Foreach($item in $itemlist)
    { 
     $output+= [int[]]@("$item").ToCharArray() -join ',' | Out-String
    }
 Write-Host $output
```

I'm trying to get all this in a single line (due to a complicated reason that prevents me from running a Powershell script) so I can run a single Powershell command to get the same effect but so far I'm having a hard time.

Given below is what I've managed to achieve.

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path "$data_path").FullName | Format-Table -Property @{n='';e={[int[]]@($_).ToCharArray() -join ','}} | Out-Host
```

The output however doesn't have the ASCII values, the paths in the output are represented in characters. Can someone please help me out with this ?

Comment: Why aren't you using `-EncodedCommand`?

Comment: It seems when you say "ASCII value," you mean UTF-16 code unit. Paths use the Unicode character set. Chars are UTF-16 code units, one or two encode a Unicode codepoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use this:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path "$data_path").FullName | ForEach-Object { [int[]]@("$_").ToCharArray() -join ',' } | Out-String
```

Answer (score 2):

How you *should* be doing it if you're running this from `cmd.exe`:

```
$Command = @'
$itemlist = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path "$data_path").FullName 
Foreach($item in $itemlist)
{ 
    $output+= [int[]]@("$item").ToCharArray() -join ',' | Out-String
}
Write-Host $output
'@
[Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($Command))
```

End result:

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -NoLogo -EncodedCommand JABpAHQAZQBtAGwAaQBzAHQAIAA9ACAAKABHAGUAdAAtAEMAaABpAGwAZABJAHQAZQBtACAALQBSAGUAYwB1AHIAcwBlACAALQBQAGEAdABoACAAIgAkAGQAYQB0AGEAXwBwAGEAdABoACIAKQAuAEYAdQBsAGwATgBhAG0AZQAgAAoAIABGAG8AcgBlAGEAYwBoACgAJABpAHQAZQBtACAAaQBuACAAJABpAHQAZQBtAGwAaQBzAHQAKQAKACAAIAAgACAAewAgAAoAIAAgACAAIAAgACQAbwB1AHQAcAB1AHQAKwA9ACAAWwBpAG4AdABbAF0AXQBAACgAIgAkAGkAdABlAG0AIgApAC4AVABvAEMAaABhAHIAQQByAHIAYQB5ACgAKQAgAC0AagBvAGkAbgAgACcALAAnACAAfAAgAE8AdQB0AC0AUwB0AHIAaQBuAGcACgAgACAAIAAgAH0ACgAgAFcAcgBpAHQAZQAtAEgAbwBzAHQAIAAkAG8AdQB0AHAAdQB0AA==
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is turning into a short contest..

```
ls $data_path -r|%{($_|% f*|% t*y|% toi*2 $null)-join','}|out-string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$itemlist = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path "$data_path").FullName; Foreach($item in $itemlist){$output+= [int[]]@("$item").ToCharArray() -join ',' | Out-String};Write-Host $output
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$data_path" | ForEach-Object { [int[]][char[]]$_.FullName -join ',' }

Get-ChildItem -Path "$data_path" | ForEach-Object { [int[]]@($_.FullName).ToCharArray() -join ',' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using aliases is all I can think of to shorten it further than anyone has so far:

```
ls "$data_path" -r | %{[int[]]@($_.FullName).ToCharArray() -join ","} | Out-String
```

Comment: To have the same result as the original code, I believe you have to take `Out-String` out of the loop - in fact it's not even needed ...

Answer (score -3):

```
 $itemlist = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path "$data_path").FullName 
 Foreach($item in $itemlist)
    { 
     $output+= [int[]]@("$item").ToCharArray() -join ',' | Out-String
    }
 Write-Host $output
```

Comment: _I'm trying to get all this in a single line (due to a complicated reason that prevents me from running a Powershell script)_